# Firefox default font size issue

Tags: css, firefox, cross-browser

Flexible layouts use ems or % as font-size units a common practice is to use body font-size as 62.5%

But Firefox's default font is 14px which results in smaller layout than others who have 16px default font size

Can't we fix just body font-size to 10px so that relative sizes works in every browser.

Comment: Firefox's default font is not 14px.  It's 16px for proportional and 14px for fixed-width fonts... and it's a preference users can set as they wish.  If you "fix" the body font-size that just means that some people who would otherwise set a 20px default font just can't read your text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, in addition to @Ray's answer..

For browser inconsitencies like these, consider using a reset stylesheet.

A good one can be found [here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). and [here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/).

I am pasting the code here for sake of reference.

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of enumerating all the elements, it is probably better to use "*" selector nowadays:
     * { margin:0; padding:0; ... }
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_all.asp

Answer (score 0):

You are saying a lot of the right things here:

- Ems and percents have traditionally been the units to use for "scalable" layouts.
- The "cascade" in CSS includes the *browser's own style sheet*.  So whenever you omit a style property for some element, it searches through the cascade and will pick up these missing properties from the browser's style sheet at the end of a chain.
- If you want pixel-perfect font handling for page text that looks the same across browsers, you will need to define a font-size yourself.  Using `px` on the `body` element should give you what you want. I'm not aware of any reason why this is still an issue.  There was a time when some people would avoid `px` but modern browsers handle zooming nicely now that I suspect it is much less of an issue than it was.